# How to return an object from a function in Kotlin?

Tags: object, kotlin, return

My code:

```
class Point(xA: Int)
{
    val x = xA
}

fun AddVectorToPoint(i: Int): Point()
{
    val x: Int = 1 + i
    val obj = Point(x)
    return obj
}

fun main()
{
    val points = mutableListOf(Point(0))
    points.add(AddVectorToPoint(2))
}
```

But when I try to compile this, I get "test.kt:6:36: error: expecting a top level declaration > fun AddVectorToPoint(i: Int): Point() {"
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove return type parentheses from `fun AddVectorToPoint(i: Int): Point()` line. It must like [this](https://pl.kotl.in/1GQwc_725).

Comment: Also, it's usual to start a function name with a lower-case letter; see the [Kotlin coding convensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parantheses after the return type

```
fun AddVectorToPoint(i: Int): Point
{
    val x: Int = 1 + i
    val obj = Point(x)
    return obj
}
```

Or to make it more concise:

```
fun AddVectorToPoint(i: Int) = Point(1 + i)
```